# How to get EST Timestamp from Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can I retrieve an EST Timestamp from Oracle database in the Format as `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'`?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by EST here? Do you mean Eastern Time (varies between UTC-5 and UTC-4) or Eastern Standard Time (always UTC-5)? And is there any reason you need to do this in SQL rather than in your client code?

Comment: checkout this function TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ() http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by `EST`?

```
SELECT tzabbrev, TZ_OFFSET(tzname), tzname  
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES tz 
WHERE tzabbrev = 'EST'
ORDER BY 1,2,3;

TZABBREV    TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)   TZNAME
EST +10:00  Australia/Brisbane
EST +10:00  Australia/Lindeman
EST +10:00  Australia/Queensland
EST +10:30  Australia/Broken_Hill
EST +10:30  Australia/Yancowinna
EST +11:00  Australia/ACT
EST +11:00  Australia/Canberra
EST +11:00  Australia/Hobart
EST +11:00  Australia/LHI
EST +11:00  Australia/Lord_Howe
EST +11:00  Australia/Melbourne
EST +11:00  Australia/NSW
EST +11:00  Australia/Sydney
EST +11:00  Australia/Tasmania
EST +11:00  Australia/Victoria
EST -05:00  America/Cayman
EST -05:00  America/Detroit
EST -05:00  America/Fort_Wayne
EST -05:00  America/Grand_Turk
EST -05:00  America/Indiana/Indianapolis
EST -05:00  America/Indiana/Marengo
EST -05:00  America/Indiana/Vevay
EST -05:00  America/Indianapolis
EST -05:00  America/Iqaluit
EST -05:00  America/Jamaica
EST -05:00  America/Kentucky/Louisville
EST -05:00  America/Louisville
EST -05:00  America/Montreal
EST -05:00  America/New_York
EST -05:00  America/Panama
EST -05:00  America/Thunder_Bay
EST -05:00  Canada/Eastern
EST -05:00  EST
EST -05:00  EST5EDT
EST -05:00  Jamaica
EST -05:00  US/East-Indiana
EST -05:00  US/Eastern
EST -05:00  US/Michigan
EST -06:00  America/Cancun
EST -06:00  America/Chicago
EST -06:00  America/Indiana/Knox
EST -06:00  America/Indiana/Petersburg
EST -06:00  America/Indiana/Vincennes
EST -06:00  America/Knox_IN
EST -06:00  America/Managua
EST -06:00  America/Rankin_Inlet
EST -06:00  CST
EST -06:00  US/Central
EST -06:00  US/Indiana-Starke
EST -07:00  America/Cambridge_Bay
```

Anyway, you can do it like this:

```
select to_char(localtimestamp at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') 
from dual;
```

or depending on your needs:

```
select to_char(localtimestamp at time zone '-06:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new_time() function:

```
select to_char(new_time(current_timestamp, 'PST', 'EST'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

The above would convert from PST to EST.

Comment: It does if you provide the proper time zone to convert from. If your oracle session (your user) is not in PST timezone then you need to use the timezone appropriate for your session timezone.